# Issue with QLayoutItem properties

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new in Qt, and I thought of creating my own Layout as my first project, but I had some problems with the **positioning** and **resizing** of my items inside my Layout, More precisely in the `setGeometry`. This is what my method looks like :

```
void Panel::setGeometry(const QRect &rect)
{
   QLayout::setGeometry(rect);

   QLayoutItem* item = itemList.at(0); // Get the item at index 0

   item->setGeometry(QRect(10,10,200,100)); // Here's the problem

}
```

My item behaves oddly, the only correct properties are (**width** and **x**), so my question is, what could cause that ? I could provide more details if you want, and any criticism is welcome (good or bad), thank you !

Comment: Does `item` point to a `QWidgetItem`?  If so does the corresponding `QWidget` (as returned by `item->widget()`) have the correct parent widget?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the implementation of `addWidget`.

Comment: Problem solved, I now have access to my widget as you told me, so I can change its properties correctly as follows: `item->widget()->resize();` I do not know if this is the right method but it works, thank's @G.M.